# Create WebSphere administrative client program for java

Tags: java, api, client, websphere

I am using IBM WebSphere server. I need to Create WebSphere administrative client program for java using WebSphere Administrative API's. I am using [this code](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tjmx_develop.html) for creating admin client

```
...
adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);
...
```

but it gives exception.

`The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host localhost at port 8881.`

After creating client I want to configure WASADMIN through this API. Am I on right track?

I need to get shared library through this API.

Comment: Have you got WAS running on localhost?

Comment: yes. Its running on localhost

Answer (score 0):

check if you have this server SOAP connector port set to 8881.

In Dmgr click the server name than Ports to check it. If not using 8881 than change it to the correct port being used by the server you're trying to connect to.

Update:

I did a test in my environment(Linux) and the following code worked( I had to add WebSphere_ND8.5/AppServer/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jarto classpath to run it without getting a ClassNotFoundException):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClient;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory;
import com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException;

public class AdminConnect {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AdminConnect.class.getName());
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties connectProps = new Properties();
    connectProps.setProperty(
    AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);

    connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "localhost");
    connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "8880");
//      connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "test2");
//      connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "user24test");
    AdminClient adminClient = null;
    try
    {
           adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps);
           logger.info("Connected successfuly with WebSphere :) ");
    }
    catch (ConnectorException e)
    {
           logger.severe("Exception creating admin client: " + e);
           e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: I checked and there is no problem with PORT.

Comment: Are you using a linux box? Maybe a local firewall like iptables is blocking you from reaching the server. It's really strange problem. Also can you check WAS logs SystemOut.log and check to wich address WAS in biding? (Localhost or DNS name?)

Comment: If you're using windows than check the windows firewall about blocking that specific port. I have also updated my answer with working code I have just tested. Please notice I have commented the username and pwd as in my local testing environment I am not using security. Try it. Regards

Comment: I checked. Firewall is OFF.

Comment: Have you tried the example I have posted? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: well, getting out of ideas here.. Can you ping localhost? also, can you reach Dmgr using localhost address? Is your WAS configuration a standalone server or a full N.D configuration with Dmgr + managed servers?

Comment: localhost is responsive. WAS configuration are standalone.